# Samba setup: RHEL, Windows 7

Tags: windows, networking, windows-7, samba, network-share

service smb restart; service winbind restart; service nmb restart
 service smb stop; service winbind stop; service nmb stop

I, for the kick of it, thought I'll setup a samba server on my office network, so I can edit my code on windows using my fav editor, and run it on linux. It's didn't work using the "quick and dirty" configurations I found after on the www. By doesn't work I mean that after starting the 3 samba deamons on my linux box, I type in \\MYHOSTSAMBA in windows explorer and it pops up a dialog saying "**Windows can not access \\MYHOSTSAMBA.** Check the spelling...".

Any help is appreciated:

Env:

RHEL 6: Linux MYHOST 2.6.32-358.11.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed May 15 10:48:38 EDT 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

```
(0)root@MYHOST$ dnsdomainname
dev.abc.com
(0)root@MYHOST$
```

Windows 7: Laptop from which I'm hoping to access the samba share is in a domain like this: global.xyz.abc.com. (it's not part of a workgroup). I can't change this. Note that my linux box is on dev.abc.com and win 7 laptop is on global.xyz.abc.com.

- Samba: Version 3.6.9-151.el6 (smbcontrol -V)

So far what I've done is:

```
(0)root@MYHOST# cat /etc/samba/smb.conf
[global]
        workgroup = GLOBAL.XYZ.ABC.COM
        netbios name = MYHOSTSAMBA
        security = SHARE
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        local master = No
        dns proxy = No
        idmap config * : backend = tdb

[Data]
        comment = kashyap
        path = /tmp
        read only = No
        guest ok = Yes

(0)root@MYHOST# service smb restart; service winbind restart; service nmb restart
Shutting down SMB services:                                [  OK  ]
Starting SMB services:                                     [  OK  ]

Shutting down Winbind services:                            [  OK  ]
Starting Winbind services:                                 [  OK  ]
Shutting down NMB services:                                [  OK  ]
Starting NMB services:                                     [  OK  ]
(0)root@MYHOST#
```

**Only thing of interest I saw in log file /var/log/samba/log.nmbd was:**

```
[2013/10/11 14:53:52,  0] nmbd/nmbd_workgroupdb.c:57(name_to_unstring)
  name_to_nstring: workgroup name GLOBAL.XYZ.ABC.COM is too long. Truncating to GLOBAL.XYZ.ABC
```

I assume this might be a/the problem, but have no clue. Any help is appreciated.

Rest of the logs in /var/log/samba seem ok:

```
(1)root@plabb54# tail -5 log.nmbd
  name_to_nstring: workgroup name GLOBAL.XYZ.ABC.COM is too long. Truncating to GLOBAL.XYZ.ABC
[2013/10/11 14:57:02,  0] nmbd/nmbd_workgroupdb.c:57(name_to_unstring)
  name_to_nstring: workgroup name GLOBAL.XYZ.ABC.COM is too long. Truncating to GLOBAL.XYZ.ABC
[2013/10/11 14:57:02,  0] nmbd/nmbd_workgroupdb.c:57(name_to_unstring)
  name_to_nstring: workgroup name GLOBAL.XYZ.ABC.COM is too long. Truncating to GLOBAL.XYZ.ABC
(0)root@plabb54# tail -5 log.smbd
  Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2011
[2013/10/11 14:56:27.500666,  0] printing/print_cups.c:151(cups_connect)
  Unable to connect to CUPS server localhost:631 - Connection refused
[2013/10/11 14:56:27.501012,  0] printing/print_cups.c:528(cups_async_callback)
  failed to retrieve printer list: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
(0)root@plabb54# tail -5 log.winbindd
[2013/10/11 14:56:27,  0] winbindd/winbindd.c:1348(main)
  winbindd version 3.6.9-151.el6 started.
  Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2011
[2013/10/11 14:56:27.372804,  0] winbindd/winbindd_cache.c:3147(initialize_winbindd_cache)
  initialize_winbindd_cache: clearing cache and re-creating with version number 2
(0)root@plabb54# tail -5 log.wb-MYHOSTSAMBA
(0)root@plabb54# tail -5 log.wb-BUILTIN
(0)root@plabb54# tail -5 log.winbindd-idmap
(0)root@plabb54#
```

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be...

Windows 7, by default, wants to use NTLMv2, rather than the LAN Manager or NTLMv1.  Try adding **client ntlmv2 auth = yes** to your SMB.CONF file, or down-grading your client's behaviour via Local Security Policy (or GPO).